# Can I mix RON 97 fuel with RON 95 fuel in my car?

Tags: gasoline, fuel-pump, octane

sorry for asking a noob question.
My car uses unleaded petrol car.

I have been using RON 95 fuel in my car. It is half tank full.

Now I got £2.80 discount on Shell V-Power.

Can I pump RON 97 fuel (Shell V-Power) in my car? Maybe for the half of the tank or maybe for 10 litre?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely you can mix different octanes of petrol (gasoline) in your car, it won't hurt your car and you may get better performance with a more expensive fuel. Premium fuels are generally better quality, have more energy per unit as well as detergents so they definitely won't hurt (I'm not advocating premium fuel by the way, I think it's a ripoff most of the time). Most cars these days have octane sensors and adjust automatically to use whatever they are given.

However, you may not actually save money. Assuming UK money premium fuel is generally £0.20 more expensive per litre, it would only take 14 litres to make up the price difference, and then you are spending more money.

Comment: Covers the topic nicely.

Comment: This is a great answer, but *have more energy per unit* isn't always true, depending on what components were used in the two mixes you're comparing.